# SQL Server - How can I get the TRUNCATE TABLE log for a specific table?

Tags: sql-server, logging, truncate

We have a little strange problem in SQL Server. One of our tables is empty during the ETL. We are sure the table is loaded, but the problem is that table is emptied after.
Every day, we load several tables (by ETL). But in our process, there is a TRUNCATE TABLE statemement and we don't know where. I would like identify at least the time of the running of this TRUNCATE TABLE query. And then compare it with the Agent Job history. In order to know which job runs it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Truncate isn't in the default trace. You would either need to have auditing turned on (Enterprise only) or create a ddl trigger on the table.

Comment: Can you search for the keyword of truncate in your project?

Comment: We did it and we don't find anything :(

Comment: Are you sure it is truncating? Have you looked at the table in question in the default trace? Maybe it is being deleted and not truncated?

Comment: You can also use extended events trace, probably the best IMO. Plus your question does not have any meaning, whole point how to help you find truncate statement

Answer (score 0):

Truncate doesn't fire dml or ddl triggers. So table/database triggers won't help in this case.

You can either run a Profiler process to catch any 'truncate table' commands during the ETL processes.

The "dirtier" option is to create a schema binding view over the table, which will cause the truncate to fail, and you can see which process did.